# how can i store picture thats was i edit on my pillow code in django and upload it to the user?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to make website that can print the name of user in greeting cards but i have issue

I'm trying to save the pics on my database but icant see it save on my database as you see my code in the bottom

this my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Name
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw , ImageFont

# Create your views here.
def Home(request):
        name_input = str(request.POST.get('user_name'))

        img = Image.open("C:\\Users\\kmm\\Desktop\\my_django_stuff\\Eid_G\\files\\covers\\mypic.png")

        d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

        fnt = ImageFont.truetype('C:\\Users\\kmm\\Desktop\\fonts\\static\Cairo-Bold.ttf',40)

        message = name_input

        d.text((540,1020),message, font=fnt, fill=(237, 185, 117),anchor="ms")

        saved_i = img.save(name_input+'.png')
        save_in_model = Name(massenger_name=name_input,image=saved_i)
        save_in_model.save()

        return render(request , 'index.html')
```

and this my models.py

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.

class Name(models.Model):
    massenger_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    action_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.massenger_name)
```

and this my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'CSS/style.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="form">
      <form class="row" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="">
            <input type="textarea" class="form-control" placeholder="أكتب أسمك (مثلا/أخوكم عبدالله العتيبي)" id="text_name" name="user_name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" id="button">حمل الصورة</button>
          </div>
      </form>

      {{ Name.Image }}
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add filename to

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',blank=True,null=True)
```

like this piece of code

```
def upload_file_name_path(instance, filename_ext):
    ext = filename_ext.split('.')[-1]
    return f'images/{URL_SAFE(instance.name)}-{randint(1000, 10000)}.{ext}'

class Name(models.Model):
    massenger_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    action_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_file_name_path,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.massenger_name)
```